# Anylogic assign agent from population of agents to fluidsource batch

Tags: anylogic

I create a spreadsheet with some properties (columns); then in Anylogic create an agent (population of agents) and load it from DB.  Run model.  Works perfectly, it shows I have an Agent population "products" with 6 agents..  (model has FluidSource, Pipe, Tank, Valve, FluidDispose, all basic configuration)

So now I open the FluidSource, select Custom batch and for Batch:  `products.get[0].productName`  (productName is parameter of type string).  I have also tried:

```
products[0];
products[0].productName;
products.get(0);
```

Now run again.. in model window it says "*Error while drawing animation frame...*" (orange block top right)
and in model.Console it says: *Error during model creation:
Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 ...*

What am I doing wrong?  How do I assign my FluidSource batch to one of my "Product" agents?

Comment: So I take out the "Custom batch" option again (leave it to default batch), add a Text and a Button and code the Button's action:    products.get(0).productName;    and run.  It shows I have six products in my agent population as before and when I press the button my text display "ULP95" - which is the correct name for my first "Product" agent - so nothing wrong with the code ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order of initialization: your FluidSource object is trying to access the `products` population *before* that population is actually filled with agents.

Make your FluidSource account for this by using this conditional check:

```
products.size() == 0 ? "InitialBatch" : products[0].productName
```

Comment: Thank You!  Works for setting initial batch.  Then later in code may use same source with different product through the inject(amount, batch, color) function.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: sorry, not clear what you mean. I suggest you turn it into a new, clear question. Always try to ask specific questions on 1 problem here, so others with the same problem can benefit in the future as well. And please mark the response as "useful" so others see it did help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info :-)